# Remove Money Decimal Query and pad zeros SQL Select

Tags: sql, currency

I am looking for some guidance.  I am running a select on a wage where I need the results to remove the decimal and pad zeros to the end.

```
isnull(rtrim(convert(char(11), c2.wage)), space(11)) as 'DN62',
```

In the example above I am pulling 1384.61 but need to result to 13846100000.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: which dbms are you using?

Comment: Just multiply it by 10000000

Comment: This seems like a very odd requirement unless your numbers read from right to left. How would you tell the difference between a salary of 10,000 and 100,000? I'd normally expect the padding with zeroes on the left.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using SQL Server. The following would work for you:

```
SELECT LEFT(REPLACE(Cast(ISNULL(1384.61,0) as varchar), '.', '') + '0000000000',11)
```

Another way is to multiply your number for the required zeros. Use one of these solutions as per your situation. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.

Comment: I'm glad that i helped you :) Please accept it as answer and upvote it to help others as well :)

Comment: LEFT(REPLACE(Cast(ISNULL(c2.preinjwage,0) as varchar), '.', '') + '0000000000',11) as 'DN62', Thanks!